# Como limpar o console no Python?

Tags: python, terminal

Sou usuário do Sistema Operacional `Ubuntu` e, quando quero limpar o Terminal, eu utilizo o comando `clear`.

```
>>> clear
```

Porém, no `Python`, como eu poderia fazer para poder limpar o terminal, quando eu o utilizo na linha de comando?

Existe alguma maneira simples de fazer isso?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
import os
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
```

Segue o link do SOen, [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python), tem outras alternativas também.

Comment: Pela sua resposta, acabo de aprender a detectar o Sistema operacional :)

Answer (score 38):

Simplesmente pressione `ctrl + L`   (funciona no shell também - você nem precisa escrever  `clear`).

Isso no terminal. Em um programa, você pode simplesmente imprimir um número de linhas em branco maior que o tamanho do terminal: `print("\n" * 130)`, ou, se estiver no Linux ou Mac, imprimir a sequência ANSI que apaga a tela:
`print("\x1b[2J")`. Veja mais detalhes abaixo.

O CTRL + L limpa a tela se você estiver no terminal de algum Linux - e talvez um ou outro dos ambientes interativos do Windows - mas não no Idle, e outros prompts do Python integrados a IDE's - e certamente não é apropriado se você desejar apagar a tela de dentro de um programa (você não pode pedir ao usuário para digitar "ctrl + L" para apagar a tela :-)  )

A razão de não existir uma chamada de função simples,na biblioteca padrão do Python, é que as entradas e saídas padrão não são pensadas, numa linguagem de programação genérica, sempre como um "terminal" - elas representam um fluxo de dados de entrada, e dois de saída (stdout e stderr). Mas a linguagem em si "não sabe" que está rodando no terminal quando algum programa é executado. Para programas feitos específicamente para o terminal que queiram uma interação mais sofisticada (inclusive com o mouse), a biblioteca padrão do Python inclui o módulo `curses` (veja abaixo).

A solução chamando o comando externo - seja o `cls` no windows ou `clear` no Linux/Mac OS, com o `os.system` funciona -mas tem um problema básico: é um programa externo - todo um processo externo no sistema operacional, achar o arquivo no disco, criar o processo, para fazer uma chamada de API ao terminal. Em termos de usos de recursos **é o mesmo que chamar um chaveiro para abrir e trancar a porta de novo cada vez que for sair de casa**.

Bom - esses programas para "apagar a tela" - tanto o clear do Unix quanto o "cls" do DOS, quanto o "clear" e o próprio o próprio CTRL + L, não fazem muito mais do que simplesmente imprimir várias linhas em branco, de forma que o conteúdo da tela atual role pra cima.

Para fazer isso em Python, basta imprimir uma única string com um número suficiente de "linefeeds" (o caractere representado por '\n' - cujo código em decimal é "10").

Um pouco mais chato é saber o número exato de linefeeds necessário para apagar a tela exatamente e sem linefeeds a mais. Se isso não for uma preocupação, um número como 130 linhas em branco é mais que suficiente para rolar um terminal em full HD com fonte em tamanho 4 - então simplesmente:

```
print ("\n" * 130)
```

Garantidamente vai te apagar qualquer terminal, independente do tipo de S.O. sem precisar executar um outro processo fora do interpretador Python só para isso.

Claro que é mais elegante imprimir um número de linhas em branco só igual ao número de linhas do terminal - e não mais que isso. Entre outras coisas, um usuário acostumado ao uso do terminal pode esperar poder rolar a tela para cima para ver a tela anterior nas linhas imediatamente precedentes à primeira linha da tela em branco (embora o comando `clear` resete esse histórico também).

Para isso, a partir do Python 3.3, há a função `get_terminal_size` no módulo OS do Python. Para quem está escrevendo um programa que vai funcionar em várias versões do Python, a funcionalidade pode ficar encapsulada numa função do tipo:

```
def clear():
    try:
        import os
        lines = os.get_terminal_size().lines
    except AttributeError:
        lines = 130
    print("\n" * lines)
```

Mas no Python 3.3 ou acima, basta fazer:

```
import os
print("\n" * os.get_terminal_size().lines)
```

Além disso, nos Unixes, e talvez em alguns programas de terminal/prompt do Windows, são reconhecidas as "[sequências ANSI](http://bluesock.org/~willkg/dev/ansi.html)" - isso é, o próprio terminal reconhece sequências especiais de caracteres que representam comandos tais como limpar a tela, alterar a cor da fonte, posicionar o cursor -etc - São um "brinquedo" bem interessante - e bem mais simples que o módulo `curses` do Python(do qual falo abaixo). Para apagar a tela em qualquer terminal Linux ou na maior parte dos Unixes (não sei se no Mac OS X funciona direto) - basta imprimir a sequência "\x1b[2J" - (o "\x1b" é o caractére `<ESC>` o mesmo código que é gerado pela tecla com esse nome). A sequência `<ESC>[` inicia várias sequências ANSI. Para ver as sequências exatas suportadas pelo seu terminal, execute o comando `infocmp` no shell.

Por essa técnica, apagar a tela, e posicionar o cursor na primeira linha e primeira coluna pode ser feito assim:

```
print("\x1b[2J\x1b[1;1H")
```

(O comando print imprime por padrão um "\n" - se estiver no Python 3 use `print("\x1b[2J\x1b[1;1H", end="")` para evitar ir parar na segunda linha - em Python2, vale a pena colocar um `from __future__ import print_function` no começo do arquivo e fazer o mesmo.)

Lembrando que - e pelo que entendi do contexto dessa pergunta - se  a idéia é só apagar a tela enquando se está no modo interativo do Python - nesse caso, o "ctrl + L" vai servir bem.

Para quem quiser fazer um programa complexo com interação pelo terminal, minha dica sempre é a seguinte: se voê está nesse ponto, é hora de pensar em fugir do terminal. Python permite interação com várias bibliotecas gráficas para criação de um aplicativo em uma janela própria - que é muito mais confortável para o usuário final.  Usuários acostumados com interface de linha de comando estarão felizes com chamar o programa da linha de comando do sistema, passando opções diretamente na mesma  - para isso consulte o módulo [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) da biblioteca padrão.

Se mesmo assim se o autor preferir criar uma interface interativa no terminal, a dica é usar o módulo [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) - também da biblioteca padrão - com ele você obtem um objeto do tipo "janela" (de texto) no terminal, onde pode posicionar o cursor em lugares exatos, apagar a tela, mudar cores, etc... E com algum trabalho (não pouco) poderá fazer um aplicativo com uma carinha realmente profissional - desde os usuários desse programa estejam congelados no tempo desde a década de 1990. Se não for esse o objetivo, apagar a tela com o `print("\n" * 130)` é o suficiente.

Com curses, você pode apagar a tela fazendo:

```
import curses
window = curses.initscr()
window.clear()
window.refresh()
```

No entanto o terminal estará nesse modo de "aplicação" em que "print" e "input" podem ter resultados diferentes do que acontece num terminal normal. Em particular, é importante posicionar o cursor na posição desejada da tela antes de cada impressão chamando a função  `window.move(line, col)` . Ao encerrar o programa, é vital retornar o terminal para o estado normal, chamando a função `curses.endwin()`.

Comment: O autor quer que o python limpe a tela, poderia editar a sua resposta?

Comment: Não - o autor pergunta como limpar o console no terminal interativo do Python - e essa é a forma mais prática. Mas sim, a resposta está curta, -  e eu posso colocar mais tarde como fazer o Python limpar a tela. Note que nenhuma das duas outras respostas faz isso no entanto: elas chamam programas externos uqe limpam a  tela (então não é "o python").

Comment: Justamente as outras resposta são programas, pois provavelmente ele está escrevendo um programa em python que trabalhe no terminal e provavelmente ele quer que em determinada ação do programa limpe a tela e este me parece o motivo das demais respostas serem códigos python. Talvez o autor da pergunta não tenha conseguido transmitir a necessidade e isto tornaria a sua resposta válida sim. No entanto nestes casos, vale mais você comentar na pergunta qual solicitando detalhes. Leve em consideração também o escopo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Na minha leitura da pergunta há duas dicas de que o problema do autor não é escrever um porgrama - mas sim, apagar o console no modo interativo. Mas concordo que é ncessário ensa resposta para ela ser completa - vamos lá.

Answer (score 6):

Faça:

```
>>> import os
>>> clear = lambda: os.system('clear')
>>> clear()
```

Dessa forma é só tu chamar o `clear()` quando quiser limpar, se tiver no `Windows` só trocar `clear` por `cls`.

Answer (score 2):

Como você é usuário do Sistema Operacional Ubuntu e quer uma maneira simples de fazer isso. Pode fazer assim:

```
import os
os.system('clear')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
if os.name == "nt":
    os.system("clear")
else:
    os.system("cls")
```

Comment: Para formatar o texto como código fonte, use o botão `{ }`

Comment: Isso já tinha sido respondido.