# apagar a tela em python

Tags: python

Eu quero apagar a tela do usuario, como o console.clear() faz no c#. Eu estou usando o print("\n"*50) como algumas pessoas me falaram em outros posts. Mas o cursos ou o proximo print fica la em baixo da tela. Tem como colocar o curso para o topo??? se puderem tbm me explicar como o os.system('cls') funciona em um pequeno codigo, pq disseram que isso funciona mas eu não consegui usar. Obrigado.
PS.: Sou usuario windows e estou usando o python 3.

Comment: Acho que está relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72678/como-limpar-o-console-no-python