# Como limpar o que já foi escrito no terminal em lua?

Tags: lua

Após a execução do comando:

```
Print("teste")
Info = io.read()
```

Gostaria que a tela do terminal, com o `print` resultante fosse limpada

Answer (score 2):

é quase o mesmo problema que respondo nessa questão, perguntando sobre o terminal de Python [Como limpar o console no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72678/como-limpar-o-console-no-python/72811#72811)  -

Motivo: apagar o terminal não é um problema da linguagem - nem de Lua, nem de C++, nem de Python, nem de nenhuma que não seja um "framework" integrado com o terminal - como Cobol, o "Qbasic" predecessor do VisualBasic e as primeiras versões do Delphi na década de 1990 - todas elas "enxergam" a saída apenas como um arquivo de escrita de bytes (ou caracteres, nos casos em que a linguagem traduz automaticamente texto acentuado e emojis para a codificação que o terminal está usando).

Então, se você precisa de qualquer interface um pouco mais sofisticada no terminal, e no caso, bem pouco sofisticada mesmo: só apagar a tela - tem que usar comandos que o programa do terminal vai entender. Esses comandos tem o nome de "Sequências ANSI" - e além de poderem apagar a tela, também podem posicionar a impressão em qualquer posição, mudar a cor do texto, etc... Começam com um caractere "<ESC>" (código "\x1b"), seguido de alguns parâmetros e um especificador do comando. Em vez desses parâmetros aparecerem impressos no terminal, eles executam uma ação.

Esses comandos funcionam na maioria dos terminais, mas justamente não funcionam no `cmd` do Windows - (mas vão funcionar se você baixar o app de "terminal" da Windows store).

Então, para apagar a tela e posicionar o cursor na linha 1, coluna 1, basta imprimir a sequência:

```
print("\x1b[2J\x1b[1;1H")
```

Para só apagar a tela:

```
print("\x1b[2J")
```

Uma outra solução, se você está no CMD do Windows e não tem sequências ANSI, é só imprimir uma porção de linhas em branco, pelo menos uma a mais que o tamanho do terminal. Em Lua precisa fazer um `for`

```
for i=0,70,1 do
  print("\n")
end
```

Vai imprimir 70 linhas em branco.

## o que não fazer:

Por que evitar chamar "`os.execute`"?  Como está descrito na outra resposta, a chamada os.execute vai  ciniciar um outro processo no sistema operacional, carregar um shell - e tudo isso para imprimir algumas linhas em branco.

É umas 1000 a 10000 vezes mais lento, e usa o mesmo tanto de memória a mais. Não vai fazer diferença por que se você está apagando a tela, está numa sessão interativa com o usuário - e os computadores hoje são tão rápidos que mesmo assim vai ser imperceptível. Mas eu costumo dizer que usar `os.execute("clear")` para apagar a tela é equivalente a telefonar pra um chaveiro pra ele vir, e abrir sua porta de casa com as ferramentas dele, a cada vez que você vai entrar ou sair de casa (sendo que você está com a chave na mão e é só usa-la).

Mas, apesar de tudo, é só deselegante e a experiência do usuário vai ser a mesma - eu que pessoalmente me incomodo com isso (e vai funcionar diferente no linux e no Windows - mas até aí, a sequência ANSI também vai)

## Outros comandos para o terminal:

Aqui tem uma página legal com o resumo de vários comandos para o terminal:

http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php

É só lembrar de trocar "ESC" por "\x1b" - que imprime o caractere "ESC" pelo seu código (27 em decimal).
Outra dica é depois que descobrir sequências que funcionam, não deixar as sequências "cruas" no meio do seu código - quem é que vai ver um  `print("\x1b[2J")` lá no meio e vai saber que você está apagando a tela? Crie ou variáveis com as strings contendo os cmandos, ou funções que imprimam esses comandos do tipo:

```lua
function cls() 
    print("\x1b[2J\x1b[1;1H") 
end
```

Aí  - no ponto em que precisa apagar a tela, você só chama a função `cls()` - fica muito mais fácil de se preocupar só com a lógica do seu programa e os códigos de apresentação ficam numa parte separada.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o comando `os.execute()`.

No Windows:

```
os.execute("cls")
```

No Unix:

```
os.execute("clear")
```

Resposta traduzida do stackoverflow em inglês, fonte:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187310/how-do-i-clear-the-console-in-a-lua-program