# cmd fechando ao usar o comando cls/clear

Tags: python, cmd

Fiz uma função que identifica se a pessoa esta usando windows ou linux, e com isso executa o comando certo para limpar o cmd/terminal, **funcionou no console do visual studio code**, porém quando eu vou executar o arquivo .py ele fecha...

**Código:**

```
import os
import platform

def limpar():
    if (platform.system() == 'Windows'):
        os.system('cls')
    if (platform.system() == 'Linux'):
        os.system('clear')
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/72678/112052

Comment: Importante [edit] o post e fornecer um [mcve] do problema. No código fornecido a função nunca é chamada, e se acrescentar, funciona normalmente.

Answer (score 1):

**executei o seu código com algumas alterações** no Ubuntu 20.04 e deu tudo certo.

```
import os
import platform


def limpar():
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        return os.system('cls')

    os.system('clear')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    limpar()
```

Comment: Aparentemente é problema do cmd do windows, com esse código o cmd tb fechou :/

Answer (score 1):

Eu acho que você esqueceu de chamar a função limpar() no final do script!
O meu funcionou normal!
Assim eu fiz:

```
import os
import platform

def limpar():
       if (platform.system() == 'Windows'):
             os.system('cls')
       if (platform.system() == 'Linux'):
             os.system('clear')
limpar()
```